# How to creat Woocommerce Back-in-Stock-Notification over a custom button?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom button in an wordpress website:

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" onclick="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();">

<?php $productName = $product->name; ?>
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="submitData_frompopUP();">Ja   </button>
```

I also have the [woocommerce-back-in-stock-notification](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/back-in-stock-notifier-for-woocommerce/) plugin.

I would like, that when the button is clicked, the email, along with the product name is inserted to the same database the plugin uses.

I tried to go through the plugin's source code. The only thing I can find is a function `handle_form`. But I can't find any submission endpoint, which i can call by PHP.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Process is handled by JS. In `assets/js/frontend-dev.js`.

Firstly, what you have to do is during generating HTML on server you need insert into the form swg security tag. It could be something like:

```
<input type="hidden" class="cwg-security" name="cwg-security" value="<?php wp_create_nonce('codewoogeek-product_id-' . $product_id); ?>"/>
```

You need this if you want to AJAX call which will be made in JS be accepted. Then you can make JS function similar to one used by plugin.

```
function submitData_frompopUP(){
  var security =  document.getElementsByName('cwg-security')[0].value;
  var data = {
    action: 'cwginstock_product_subscribe',
    product_id: product_id, //you have to get id
    variation_id: var_id, //you have to get id
    subscriber_name: subscriber_name, //you have to get it
    subscriber_phone: subscriber_phone, //you have to get it
    subscriber_phone_meta: phone_meta_data, //you have to get it
    user_email: email_id, //you have to get id
    user_id: userid, //you have to get id
    security: security,
    dataobj: cwginstock,
  };
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: cwginstock.ajax_url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', cwginstock.security);
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        msg = msg.msg;
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
    }
  });
}
```

During testing check Developer Tools, you can get 403 Error response. It can be caused by any number of things, and all of them which are checked before response can be found in `includes/class-ajax.php` in function `ajax_subscription()`.
Hopefully it will be at least a bit helpful.

Comment: Hi what is dataobj: cwginstock ?
I can't find any mention of cwginstock in the code of the back-in-stock plugin

Comment: @Sean https://wordpress.org/plugins/back-in-stock-notifier-for-woocommerce/ - Are you investigating this plugin? If yes, there are 100+ matches in code. Structure of cwginstock is possible to find if you open dev console in your browser and run in console: `cwginstock`